# A non well formed numeric value encountered in search result pagination?

Tags: php, php-7

I have a problem in search result page, when I go to search result page, it shows search results but I am having following error on top of the search page.

> Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in
>   D:\Wamp\www\firma\test.php on line 192

Line 192:

```
 $start= intval($page - 1) * $show_in_page;
```

Here is the total code of that part:

```
$per_page_html = '';
$page = 1;
$start=0;
$show_in_page = intval("12");

if(isset($_POST["page"])){
    $page = $_POST["page"];
    $start= intval($page - 1) * $show_in_page;
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with `$show_in_page = 12`? And `$start = ($page - 1) * $show_in_page`?

Comment: Looks like nothing wrong with that part! well that is what I see, tell me is I am missing something in them ?

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming $_POST["page"] is an int and you cannot do that. You need to validate first.

You can do something like:

```
if(isset($_POST["page"])){
    if (!is_numeric($_POST["page"])) die("Non numeric input");
    $page = $_POST["page"];
    $start= intval($page - 1) * $show_in_page;
}
```

Although it will really depend on what you want to happen when a non numeric is found.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! when I use your codes it shows Error `Non numeric input`